# Can't open shop in hero siege

Tags: hero-siege

I don't know why but I can't open the shop in game I've tried with the controller pressing the `x` button but this doing nothing, after I play with the keyboard and this doing nothin when I press `p` ... The shop is unlock later in game maybe ? I am in act 2 in normal game.

### EDIT

The solution if someone search for it:

http://steamcommunity.com/app/269210/discussions/0/613940477880546623/?tscn=1414947570

Comment: If someone is interesting here is the solution : 

http://steamcommunity.com/app/269210/discussions/0/613940477880546623/?tscn=1414947570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the shop works was changed in a patch instead of pressing x you now need to visit it on the level.